# Ctrl-S moves the cursor near the top of the document in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, keyboard-shortcuts

Why is it that every time I save my file in Eclipse with Ctrl-S it moves the cursor to the top of the page I'm working on?  Coincidentally, it moves the cursor to the top of the JavaScript section of an HTML page I am editing.  It's really annoying.  How do I stop it?

Comment: Now I can't duplicate the problem.  I've tried it in two different versions of Eclipse: Indigo and Juno.  Indigo has the default editor theme and my Juno has the Aptana theme (not sure how this happened, but oh well.)  I guess it's fixed now?

Answer (score 1):

Yep, was plagued by the same annoyance. In the eclipse preferences, select javascript then editor. On the editor preferences page there is a box, checked by default, called "Smart caret positioning in JavaScript names (overrides platform behavior)". Uncheck it.

Comment: For a second it seemed like it did work, but then it didn't.  God, I hate Eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

I've got into the habit of hitting ctrl+Q immediately after ctrl+S
This brings you back to the last edited location.

Not so much a solution as a workaround, but it has stopped me pulling my hair out nonetheless.

S.