# In Eclipse, cursor keeps jumping into the Console after clicking Ctrl+S

Tags: javascript, eclipse, ctrl, oomph, suitecloud

Having studied, these articles
[Ctrl-S moves the cursor near the top of the document in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10083077/ctrl-s-moves-the-cursor-near-the-top-of-the-document-in-eclipse)
[Eclipse jumping to function name on Ctrl-S](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2131509/eclipse-jumping-to-function-name-on-ctrl-s)
I am still facing the issue that every time I hit <kbd>Ctrl + S</kbd> the Console opens and the cursor jumps into it.
It's maddening.

I am working in the SuiteCloud IDE perspective, mainly in JavaScript.

Has anyone encountered this specific issue before?

Comment: What's showing in the Console when this happens?

Comment: The console view has a button, "Show Console with Standard Output changes" - while that shouldn't be causing focus to be lost, you could still see if turning it off helps. Like @nitind said, the output you see in the Console should give us some clues as to what could be grabbing focus.

Comment: When this happens, the console is empty. There is no button "Show Console with Standard Output changes", either. https://i.postimg.cc/Xq2k50nL/console.png

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's going to help others, but in my case the problem was that the `Project` -> `Build automatically` option was ticked. Disabling it solved my issue.